# Google script - Set value in the first empty cell of a specific column?

Tags: setvalue

I need a function:
When I click a button in sheet1 the cell Sheet1!C21 (with text) should be copied into a specific column in sheet2, which is B5:B.  The function should look in column B to find the first empty cell (going downwards) and from there set the value (Sheet1!C21) for 20 rows. How do I accomplish this? I am a beginner at this so all help is appreciated.

Comment: ...it sounds like you're talking about a spreadsheet? Maybe Excel or Google Sheets? Please read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is now updated.